# How to bind multiple objects from the same page in Play Framework

Tags: java, binding, playframework, playframework-1.x

For an object Customer, I have multiple orders. So, In one page, I have a customer and multiple order objects,

```
 <select name="customer.order[0].orderType" id="orderType" >
    #{list orderTypes}
        <option value="${_.id}">${_.name}</option>
    #{/list}
</select>

<select name="customer.order[1].orderType" id="orderType" >
    #{list orderTypes}
        <option value="${_.id}">${_.name}</option>
    #{/list}
</select>
```

Model Customer:

```
public class Customer{

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
public List<Order> orders;

}
```

Model Order:

```
     public class Order{

    @ManyToOne
    public TypeOrder orderType;

}
```

Controller :

```
 public static void saveCustomerOrder(Customer customer) {
    customer.save();

    System.out.println(customer.orderType.name + " " + customer.order.size() + " " + customer.order.get(0).orderType);
}
```

So I get the the order size as 2 ; but i dont get the data for the orderType. Can anyone help me with this?
(It doesn't persist in the database, but customer object is saved)

When I do customer.save(); I would like customer to be saved and order to be saved; 
(this is just a simple sample program)

--EDIT---

It works if I save the orders separately by looping through them.

```
for(Order o : customer.orders) 
  o.save();
```

I just want to know if it is possible to save the child model when i save the parent model. Am I missing some annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way Play 1.x works, as per [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/jpa#save), you have to explicitly save every object you want to persist. So yes, you have to iterate over all the objects.